# How to extend chef resource?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to extend `Bash` resource, so that when I invoke `shm_wbash`, the command's output is placed in a log file as it runs. Since I don't want to copy all the available parameters to LWRP resource definition, I've tried to extend the original chef Bash resource like this (I'll be omitting the actual payload since that doesn't matter here):

```
class Chef
  class Resource
    class WBash < Resource::Bash
      def initialize(name, run_context=nil)
        super

        puts 123
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've put that to `cookbooks/shm/libraries/wbash.rb` and when I try to run it, I get `No resource or method named 'shm_wbash' for`Chef::Recipe "test"'`. How do I fix this?

Comment: hey, I believe the camel case is converted to lower case with underscores when they are made available as resources in the dsl. Have you tried using w_bash?

Comment: @punkle, `No resource or method named 'shm_w_bash'`

Comment: Have you tried also without the shm_? I.e. just w_bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `w_bash`

This is what chef is converting the class name to for use in the DSL.