# chef extending recipes' libraries (with testing)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chefspec

I have a chef recipe name `my_recipe` and I would like to add a library to it to assist me in getting some stuff done, while still being able to run chefspec smoothly. 
I read the [extend recipe](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html#extend-a-recipe) documentation, but couldn't find how to extends (or dynamically create) a class within the recipe namespace.

here is a snippet:

```
# my_cookbook/recipes/my_recipe.rb
foo = MyRecipe::MyClass.foo


# my_cookbook/libraries/my_class.rb
class Chef
  class Recipe
    class MyRecipe
      unless defined?(Chef::Recipe::MyRecipe::MyClass)
        class MyClass
          def self.foo
            # do stuff
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

what am I missing?
how chef translate a dsl recipe name `my_recipe` to a recipe object (`MyRecipe`)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such translation. I don't really understand where you got this whole class structure for. What you want is just:

```
module MyHelpers
  def self.foo
```

And then `MyHelpers.foo` in your recipe.

Comment: that does not work for me, as it can cause many collision if someone else has introduces the same module name within his\her development. to eliminate such a collision, i wanted to use the recipe namespace.

with that being said, i remember doing so many years ago. yet, i saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056576/how-to-extend-chef-resource), just couldn't get how chef translate the dsl to corresponding object, so i could use this object to mixin\trait my libraries\helpers.

Comment: Defining custom resources is very different from defining non-resource helper methods. Do not monkey-patch modules under `Chef::Recipe` like that. Not not, now ever :) There is no more or less risk of name collision if you just use your own namespace.